# Issues with saving Settings in a form different than default in Debug

Tags: c#, appsettings

I have C# application settings `Settings.Default.Test`. Running in debug mode I can retrieve the value of `Test` and write to `Test`. As long as I call `Settings.Default.Save()` the value persists.

If I write to `Test` in a form that is called by form1 it seems to write OK and save OK but it does not persist between each call of form2. When I open `form2` again the value for `Test` is not what I last set it at.

I have tried cleaning the solution. This seems suspiciously like it should have had an answer 20 years ago but I am having no luck.

Code:

When I run this is form1 it works as expected. When I run i form2 it works forst time but when I show form2 a second time my var test reverts to it's original version.

```
        var test = AppSettings.Default.Test;
        AppSettings.Default.Test = "Ha AAAAAA";
        AppSettings.Default.Save();
        test = AppSettings.Default.Test;
```

Comment: Reading and writing to `Properties.Settings.Default.Test` should work provided that Form1 and Form2 are in the same project.

Comment: They are in the same project.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms project? What is the .NET version?

Comment: Winforms project. C# 7.0, .NET 6.0